# combine two row in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in oracle which is already taken from some bigger tables

```
+---------------+------------+
| shop   number | Model Type |  
+---------------+------------+
| 1             | Mod-1      |  
+---------------+------------+
| 1             | Mod-2      |  
+---------------+------------+
| 2             | Mod-3      | 
+---------------+------------+
| 2             | Mod-3      | 
+---------------+------------+
| 3             | Mod-4      |
+---------------+------------+
| 3             | Mod-5      |
+---------------+------------+
| 4             | Mod-1      |
+---------------+------------+
| 4             | Mod-2      | 
+---------------+------------+
| 4             | Mod-6      | 
+---------------+------------+
| 4             | Mod-3      |
+---------------+------------+
| 5             | Mod-1      |
+---------------+------------+
```

Actually, this is combing rows based on shop in one place and making two different columns based on that, the result should look like this

```
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| shop   Number | Shop Type                       | Shop Type |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| 1             | Mod-1 & Mod-2                    | Mix       |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| 2             | Mod-3                           | Mod-3     |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| 3             | Mod-4 & Mod-5                   | Mix       |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| 4             | Mod-1 & Mod-2   & Mod-3 & Mod-6 | Mix       |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| 5             | Mod-1                           | Mod-1     |
+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

Not sure how to work on this.Please help...

Comment: Try with use listagg()

Comment: can you help me how to use it with this

Comment: Please post you SQL Query that worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL

```
select shop_number,
listagg(distinct model_type, ' & ') within group (order by model_type) shop_type,
decode(count(distinct model_type), 1, max(model_type), 'Mix') shop_type
from mytable
group by shop_number;
```

Note that `distinct` keyword in `listagg()` is added in 19c. If you uses an older version, you need to distinct before using `listagg()`

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pLd5NgSE)